# Sometimes wrong math font in headers when using KOMA's \sectfont with lineno

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, line-numbering

I am using the KOMA-Script scrbook class, and I want to have bold math in my section titles (to match the title text). For this I redefine `\sectfont`, and it works nicely.

```
\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\bfseries\sffamily\mathversion{bold}}
```

The section titles in the table of contents and the headers are not changed. However, sometimes I *do* erroneously get bold math in the headers.

I think the problem occurs when the double-page is *just* full, so that any more text would result in an overflow, and there has to be another section after the current page (so that the next page starts with a section header). Also it only happens when I use line numbers from `\usepackage{lineno}`.

**Is lineno incompatible with KOMA-Script? Is there a better way to get bold math fonts in section titles (but not in the TOC and headers)?**

I can of course just disable the line numbers as I will with my final document, but this bug makes me suspect I am doing something wrong, and something else might break. Also, I can just stuff `\nolinenumbers` into my `\sectfont` and it seems to work, but if I'm doing something wrong and fragile, then that would be just fixing the symptoms. A MWE is below (compare the top of page 6 with page 4 and 8):

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,11pt,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}

\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\bfseries\sffamily\mathversion{bold}}

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage 

\linenumbers

\chapter{Title $xyz$ containing $\chi^2$ math}
\section{Section $A$}
% this double-page is probably not full enough, but
% one more \blindtext will make it overflow
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\section{Section $B$}
% this double-page exhibits the bug.
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\section{Section $C$}
% this double-page is identical, but doesn't exhibit the bug,
% since there is no section after it (?)
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

% uncomment this and the bug appears for section C, too: 
%\section{Section $D$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\mathversion{normal}` to the head font, e.g. `\renewcommand\headfont{\mathversion{normal}\normalfont}`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! If you post it as an answer I can accept it. I guess using `\mathversion{bold}` in `sectfont` causes undefined behavior because it may or may not be invoked on a page, but there is nothing by default that undoes it - unlike `\bfseries` which is undone by `\normalfont`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\mathversion{normal}` to the head font, e.g. `\renewcommand\headfont{\mathversion{normal}\normalfont}`.

Comment: And quite probably `\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\mathversion{normal}\normalfont}` would work, too?